# SQL query output to a text file

Tags: python, sql

I got this code from an another stackflow post and it works perfectly. But now i would like to direct the output to a text file as opposed to on the screen. How can i do it?

```
import mysql.connector
from tabulate import tabulate

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="password",
            database="testDB"
          )

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT emp_name, salary FROM emp_table")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()


print(tabulate(myresult, headers=['EmpName', 'EmpSalary'], tablefmt='psql'))
```

Comment: Add a language tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.stdout` to log the output to a txt file.

Try:

```
import sys
with open('file.txt', 'w+') as sys.stdout:
    import mysql.connector
    from tabulate import tabulate

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="password",
            database="testDB"
          )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT emp_name, salary FROM emp_table")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()


    print(tabulate(myresult, headers=['EmpName', 'EmpSalary'], tablefmt='psql'))
```